# In VSTO excel workbook, how can i access a string parameter that is in excel com add in

Tags: excel, parameters, vsto, add-in

I have a public parameter that is calculated in an excel com addin called LicenseStatus, i need to access this parameter from my excel workbook application.
I am using VSTO VB.
Two applications on the same computer.

One is a COM add in which contains the parameter:

Public LicenseStatus As String

I need to access this parameter from another application which is an excel workbook. Depending on its value, some functionalities would be active or not. 
Of course, the end user should not be able to access it or change its value.

Comment: Do you have any code with what you have tried so far? If so, edit your question and add it for better help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a public member (method or property) to the VSTO add-in class and then access it from another applications. See [Calling Code in Application-Level Add-ins from Other Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx) for more information.